# angular-ui-select2 query function not defined when used within another directive

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-select2, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to use the angular-ui-select2 module within another directive but I receive the following error:

> query function not defined for Select2 undefined

When I place the following code in a page of it's own, it works fine:

```
<input ng-model="select2" data-ui-select2="select2Options" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Can you show us your directive code?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by my code from the link function to the controller function in my directive.